# How can one generate plots having regions filled with vector hatching?

Tags: plotting

I'm using Mathematica 13.3, I want to have a vector output image from all of my plots using hatch filling.

For a test code:

```
RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > 1/4, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {RGBColor["#0077BB"], HatchFilling[]},
 BoundaryStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

But the output ALWAYS contains bitmap fractures...clearly visible after zooming. How it can be solved with hatch filling.

[image]

Comment: I can see the very small "fractures" also in the documentation of `HatchFilling`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Export` such drawing to `pdf` is not a vector format `pdf` file. We use `Mesh` to draw such hatchfilling instead.

```
plot = RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > 1/4, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thickness[0.01], PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 80, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 - #1 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> {RGBColor["#0077BB"], AbsoluteThickness[1.5]}]
Export["test.pdf", plot] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

[image]

- For `20 Degree` slope, since the equation of such lines are `y=Tan[20 Degree] x  +b` ( where `b` is variety), so we can set  `MeshFunctions -> {#2 - Tan[20 Degree] #1 &}` to change the angle of lines.

```
Clear[plot];
plot = 
 RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > 1/4, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thickness[0.01], PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 200, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 - Tan[20 Degree] #1 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> {RGBColor["#0077BB"], AbsoluteThickness[1]}];
Export["test.pdf", plot] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

Comment: Nice replacement of Hatching. One question related to usage of {#2 - #1 &}...The filling inside a region requires two things: Spacing between lines & angle of those lines. If you can suggest something in MeshFunction that can fulfil this.

Comment: Thanks^Infinity...